# MySQL Server install fails with the following error

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-server-2012

I tried installing MySQL Server versions 5.5 as well as 5.1, both fail at the same following stage:

```
mysql-server-5.1-winx64:6 - Looking for valid template
mysql-server-5.1-winx64:100 - Failed to process template.
mysql-server-5.1-winx64:100 - Product configuration controller finished configuration.
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot this for quite some time and am running out of ideas. I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you looked here?: [mysql_bugs] (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64177)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I found that article prior to posting and tried the suggestions mentioned with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a custom install by changing the default Data File Path provided. Alter it to a path that your user has privileges !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this. I changed from the default path to `C:/Program Files/MySQL/` did not change the outcome. Moreover, I am administrator with full privileges.

Comment: Set you service to LocalSystem and Automatic ! ans start your service manually

Comment: I would like to try, however, I am not sure I understand the steps. Can you please explain?

Comment: from your cmd line type 'services' -- will list the services installed and their prop- here you alter the prop as i have said !

Comment: Okay, I don't have a service named `LocalSystem` in my list of services.

Comment: use 'local service' - take for example an account that is used to start a service that works with no problems